# If an aircraft diverts to another airport for mechanical reasons, does the dispatcher create a new flight plan?

Tags: weight, flight-plans, dispatch, enroute, diversion

Let's say the aircraft is flying from LEJ (Leipzig/Halle Airport, Germany) to DXB (Dubai International). And enroute if the aircraft needs to divert over Turkey to land because of one engine failure, what will the dispatcher do with reference to giving a new flight plan from the point of diversion over Turkey to new airport?

Will a new flight plan be executed and provided to the flight enroute? And what will be the plan if the landing weights are exceeded to the diversion alternate enroute?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no new flight plan created for the diversion. An engine-out is an emergency situation, the pilot takes whatever action they feel is needed to save the plane, and the paperwork can wait until they're safely on the ground.

If the plane is overweight for the landing, then, again, the pilot is in charge of deciding how to handle it. If they decide it's safe to do so, they can fly around burning or dumping fuel until they're at a safe landing weight. If not, then they'll just land overweight and hope that they can stop the plane before it reaches the end of the runway.

Comment: Landing performance data includes overweight landing cases, so stopping distance would be a known, not a "hope". The main consequence of the overweight landing would be maintenance inspections of everything that might be damaged, even though such damage is quite rare.

Comment: Since an overweight landing due to an inflight mechanical emergency will require inspection/repair of the malfunctioning equipment, the time spent doing the overweight landing inspection/repair would probably happen simultaneously and probably not significantly delay the aircraft's return to flight.

Comment: Dear Freeman, Thanks.. please advise what a flight dispatcher 
needs to  do if any onboard equipment becomes inoperative or unserviceable      for an Enroute flight with reference to navigation, and communication procedures including the release or continuance of a flight.

Comment: @XavierMendes I'd advise that you ask a whole new question.

Comment: I’d advise that you stop asking homework questions.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of an IFR flight plan is to tell the controllers where the plane wants to fly. Once the pilots start talking to the ATC and get their initial clearance, the routing can be amended any time by ATC, whether on pilot request or for other operational reasons, and this is just coordinated among the controllers and entered in their system.

An engine failure is an emergency, so the controller will mark the aircraft as having an emergency in the system, and might update the destination in the system. But even for diversions that are not emergency, the controller just updates the data in the system. No need to involve the dispatcher. Even if it is actually the dispatcher requesting the diversion—sometimes something fails on the airplane that allows it to fly on, but because fixing it in the original destination would be difficult, the dispatcher asks the plane to return to base or another hub and arranges different plane to complete the flight—but they still don't file another flight plan, just tell the pilots to request return to base and pilots handle it with ATC.